# How do I convert a System.Type to a Uri?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a System.Type object that represents the page I want to load. This page may come from the current assembly or another library. Is there a generic way to convert it to a System.Uri that I can pass to Frame.Navigate?

Answer (score 1):

The only common interface that's standard between the two is that all objects implement ToString() and one or more of the System.Uri constructors takes a string.

Anything beyond that will need to be of your own creation.

Answer (score 1):

Page Types and Page URIs are not necessarily a clean mapping, but if you've not done anything crazy, you could do something like this:

```
        Type blah;
        var location = new Uri("/" + blah.Name + ".xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```

Comment: Closer. Unfortunately that doesn't work unless the class blah is in root folder of the project.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was saying above about doing anything crazy. The problem is that you might not have enough information. The namespace of the type might help you in determining a location, but there isn't anything requiring that they line up.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a perfect solution. It requires the Assembly Name and Root Namespace to match. It also requires the asseblies folder structure to match its namespace structure.

```
var assemblyName = pageType.Assembly.FullName.Substring(0, pageType.Assembly.FullName.IndexOf(","));
var pageName = pageType.FullName;
pageName = pageName.Substring(assemblyName.Length+1);
pageName = pageName.Replace(".", "/");

var targetString = string.Format("/{0};component/{1}.xaml",assemblyName, pageName);
var targetUri = new Uri(targetString, UriKind.Relative);
```

Comment: Reference: http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/wp7-navigating-to-a-page-in-different-assembly